# Python file won't run in vs code using play button

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

i wrote a basic python program and tried running it using the play button but nothing happens,
i look through the interpreters and the one for python isnt detected
can someone guide me

tried looking online for answers but most are confusing since i can't seem to find some of the settings they are recommending  i use

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, my suggestion would be :**

1. First check the installation of python on your machine, and if it
   doesn't help then,
2. Open keyboard shortcuts in VS Code 'CTRL + K and CTRL + S' or by
   clicking settings button in bottom-left corner.
3. Search "Run Python File in Terminal".
4. You will get first option with the same title.
5. Double click the Key Binding area in front of title.
6. And set a keyboard shortcut for running Python {eg: 'ALT + Q' (My shortcut)}. This would be much
   convenient.